# How does this binding change my original collection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm, uwp

This is my xaml code:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:EditStudentDataViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Padding="20" Margin="20">

        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}" Header="First Name" />
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.LastName,Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Last Name" />
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.RollNumber,Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Roll Number" />
        <StackPanel Visibility="Visible" x:Name="buttons">
        <Button Content="Next" Name="Addmore"  Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Addmore_Click}"/>
        <Button Content="Done" Name="done" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.done_Click}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="edit_button" >
            <TextBox Header="Father Name" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.FatherName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Header="Mother Name" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.MotherName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Header="Father Contact No." Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.FatherContactNumber,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Header="Permanent Address" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.PermanetAddress,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Header="Current Address" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.CurrentAddress,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Header="Email Address" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.STU.EmailAddress,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Done" Name="editbutton" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.edit_student_data}"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And this is my C# code in the ViewModel:

```
class SomeClassName
{
    Student stu = Working.Selected_student();
    public Student STU { get { return stu; } set { stu = value; } }
    public void edit_student_data()
    {
        var hhjc = Teacher.all_the_classes_under_teacher;
        Working.edit_student_data(stu);
        Working.edit = false;
    }
}
```

And this is my function to get the student object in other class:

```
public static Student Selected_student()
{
    try
    {
        var stu = Teacher.all_the_classes_under_teacher.Single(x => x.classname == Selected_class_name).
        studentList.Single(x => (x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName) == selected_student_name);
        return stu;
    }catch(Exception ee)
    {
        return new Student();
        }
    }
```

NOTE:I only posted the relevant code associated withe this problem.

Stament in my ViewModel `Student stu = Working.Selected_student();` retrieve the student that is selected. In the XAML file all the text-box elements retrieve the text from the public property STU.
My main problem is very simple and yet confusing. Changes in the public object, that is STU changes the private object stu but how can it change my original collection of `Teacher.all_the_classes_under_teacher` I place i break point on `Working.edit_student_data(stu);` in my Viewmodel so that i can see the changes by hovering to my original collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It changes everywhere because you are using the same instance of your student object that originated from your source collection.

Instance of student that you are returning from `Selected_student` is what is used in your Viewmodel and xaml binding. When you change a property through editing the textbox of one of your bound property; you are actually editing the original instance, which is still sitting inside your collection.

`Public STU` (as well as the `private stu`) is still the same object that was returned from `Selected_Student`.